# Piping stdout to specific location, Linux

Tags: linux, redirect, pipe, piping

i hope you'll get my point here :)

without piping the command is:

```
aircrack-ng handshakes.cap -w wordlist.txt
```

redirecting crunch stdout to aircrack:

these commands are not working:

```
crunch 8 8 abc123 | aircrack-ng handshakes.cap -w -

crunch 8 8 abc123 | aircrack-ng handshakes.cap -w-

crunch 8 8 abc123 | aircrack-ng handshakes.cap -w
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding your use case here. First off. remove the `-` from your `gedit` pipe. eg. `echo file.txt | gedit`.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the last two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
crunch 8 8 abc123 | aircrack-ng -w "-" handshakes.cap
```

Comment: @WiFry, Hey man, any time.

Answer (score 0):

The other thing to try would be process substitution:

```
aircrack-ng handshakes/PTCL-Broadband.cap -w <(crunch 8 8 abc123)
```

Whether this works will depend on exactly what aircrack wants to do with the input file.

You can also do it in two goes:

```
crunch 8 8 abc123 > /tmp/somefile
aircrack-ng handshakes/PTCL-Broadband.cap -w /tmp/somefile
```

Comment: Thanks.. 
    aircrack-ng handshakes/PTCL-Broadband.cap -w <(crunch 8 8 abc123)
this is not working but looked great at first look really ;) thanks anyway, second solution is definitely working.